# webブラウザによってFormタグの動作に違いがありますか？（django, Chrome）

Tags: django, google-chrome, safari, browser

お世話になります。周りに質問する相手もおらず、このサイトでお答えいただけると本当に助かってます。

標題の通りの質問なのですが、、

Djangoで一通り作成を終え、
Chromeで動作確認をしていたところ、

汎用CreateViewでの動作が不信だったので質問しました。

### ◆　環境

Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda, Inc.
Django 2.1.7
django-allauth 0.39.1
django-crispy-forms 1.7.2
django-filter 2.1.0

---

◆　状況

CreateViewで、ModelFormを使用し、crispy-formsにてフォームを出力していたのですが、

どうやっても保存ができず、、2時間くらい困っていました。

ふと思いつきで、サファリを使ったところ、何もソースを変更していないのに、保存ができました。

◆　思ったこと

最初は、外部キーがたくさん入っているし、フィールドの設定もかなり勘頼りで、それぞれの公式サイトをみながら進めたので、

まず、
①　自分の書き方に問題があるのではないか？
※　チュートリアル付きでプロジェクトのサンプルをgitにも挙げられているところを見ながら進めたので、gitのサンプルは動作したし、自分があっちこっちから組み合わせたのが悪いのではないか？

②　フォームや、サーバーの動作について不理解なのではないか？

③　そもそもバグ

の3つで考えていたのですが、、

ブラウザを変えて見たところ、動作してしまったので、、

④　原因がブラウザにあるのではないか？

というところで、調べ方がわからず止まってしまい、自分の知識では、どう調べれば良いかわからず、質問させていただいています。

ブラウザが原因じゃなければ、また一つ一つ調べて勉強して行きたいと思いますので、ぜひご教示いただければ幸いです。

そもそも、自分の調べ方の順番に間違いがあるでしょうか？

プロの方々の意見がいただければ幸いです。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 「どうやっても保存ができず」とは何をどこに保存できないと言う意味ですか？問題とは想定した結果と実際の結果の差です。これを明確にしないと回答を得るのは難しいです。それから、正常に動作しないのであれば、まず最初に見るのはログです。

Comment: ブラウザによって<form>の挙動が違うことはあり得ますが、「保存ができない」という問題がその違いに起因するかどうかは、情報が少なくてわかりません。フォームが送信されているなら送信内容の差を調べ、そもそも送信されていないならブラウザの開発者ツールで調べます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！そもそも問題がブラウザではなさそうなので、別の質問をあげます！お手数をお掛け致しました！